# Separate elements of CamelCase words

Tags: text-processing

Is there a way to split CamelCase words at the "internal" word boundaries in a text?

For example, given the string:

```
IamHelloTest forYou PickTest;
```

as input, I would like to produce as output:

```
Iam
Hello
Test
for
You
Pick
Test
```

**Update:** now that the question has many helpful answers, how would I proceed to include the following cases too?

Input:

```
IamTestECHO TEST PickFoo BARFull;
```

Desired output:

```
I
am
Test
ECHO
TEST
Pick
Foo
Bar
FULL
```

**Update:** how would I proceed to include the underscore too?

Input:

```
IamTestECHO TEST PickFoo BARFull def_python_FunctionTwo;
```

Desired output:

```
I
am
Test
ECHO
TEST
Pick
Foo
Bar
FULL
def
python
Function
Two
```

Comment: Your pattern is unclear. Please edit your question to include more details. What exactly is the condition?

Comment: Note: "PickTest" is commonly called PascalCase, distinguished from "forYou" camelCase.

Comment: Please do not change or amend the question after answers have already been given without at least an additional notice; it makes understanding the answers difficult for readers who did not follow the time-evolution of your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deal with your second example, a suggest a more "rule based" approach.
Consider the following Perl script (`camelcaseproc`):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -CSDA -p

s{  \W+                                     # break on non-word
 |  _                                       # break on "_"
 |  (?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu})                   # ...aB... → ...a-B...
 |  (?<=\p{Lu})(?=\p{Lu}\p{Ll})             # ..ABCd.. → ...AB-Cd.
 |  (?<=I)(?=am)                            # exceptions rules
 }{-}xg                                     #
```

- Line 1: use Unicode (to process accents, Cyrillic)
- Line 2: substitute non-letters by "\n"
- line 3,4,5: break-intraWord rules (defined by left context, rigth context)
- line 5: exception rules for "Iam"
- line 5: `x` option makes possible to add comments in regular expressions

After the usual `chmod +x camelcaseproc` we can use it as:

```
$ camelcaseproc <<< "IamTestECHO TEST PickFoo BARFull"
I-am-Test-ECHO-TEST-Pick-Foo-BAR-Full

$ camelcaseproc input-file

$ echo "IamTestECHO TEST PickFoo BARFull" | camelcaseproc
```

Comment: hello, can you organize the command like this? `echo "IamTestECHO TEST PickFoo BARFull" | perl -n -e "xxx"`

Comment: The solution presented can be used as `echo "IamTestECHO TEST PickFoo BARFull" | ./camelcaseproc` ; it is possible to `echo "...." | perl -CSDA -pe 's{\W+|(?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu})|(?<=\p{Lu})(?=\p{Lu}\p{Ll})|(?<=I)(?=am)}{\n}g'` but it is much harder to maintain.

Comment: it's fantasy, thank you. if I have the underscore in the words, how can do this?

Comment: Assuming you want it to be a separator, we can add a new rule  (one more pattern - see my edit)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/565043/grep-or-perl-for-camel-case-or-snake-case I have another more harder question, can you have a try?

Comment: Apparently The solution presented works find with that.

Comment: `perl -CSDA -pe 's{\W+|(?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu})|(?<=\p{Lu})(?=\p{Lu}\p{Ll})|(?<=I)(?=am)}{\n}g'`

Answer (score 7):

If your `grep` implementation supports `-o` (and is not the ast-open implementation which chokes with `-o` for regexps that match the empty string):

```
grep -o '[[:upper:]]*[[:lower:]]*'
```

Comment: Nice, a GNU grep / pcre version would be `grep -Po '\p{Lu}*\p{Ll}*'`. But that will not separate the `I` from the `Am` in `IAmTheMountain` (which admittedly, may be EXACTLY what the OP wants).

Comment: @mosvy I would think it wouldn't be desirable. It can be fixed with `'[[:upper:]]\?[[:lower:]]*'` or `grep -Po '\p{Lu}?\p{Ll}*'` as per your PCRE version.

Comment: it just output Iam
Hello
Test, the words after space not printed

Answer (score 4):

With GNU grep, using Unicode character properties and zero-width assertions:

```
grep -Po '((?<!=\p{Lu})\p{Lu}|(?<!=\pL)\pL)\p{Ll}*'

$ echo 'IamHelloTest forYou PickTest;' | grep -Po '((?<!=\p{Lu})\p{Lu}|(?<!=\pL)\pL)\p{Ll}*'
Iam
Hello
Test
for
You
Pick
Test
$ echo 'АямГеллоТест форЮ ПикТест' | grep -Po '((?<!=\p{Lu})\p{Lu}|(?<!=\pL)\pL)\p{Ll}*'
Аям
Гелло
Тест
фор
Ю
Пик
Тест
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed -Ee 's/([a-z])([A-Z])/\1\n\2/g' < your_file
```

With `grep`:

```
grep -Eo '[A-Z][a-z]+' < your_file
```

Comment: I just tried out your suggestions, and they don't seem to work (at least with the GNU variants): the `sed` call merges fields across separating space (as in `Test for`, `You Pick`), and the `grep` call doesn't work with words that start with a lower-case character ...

Comment: Maybe edit your question to be more specific about what should happen around "whitespace", beginning and end of words (starting/ending with uppercase/lowercase), punctuation etc... And adding a second stage to split lines on white space is rather trivial...

Comment: You're missing the opening single quote to quote the sed expression. Also, while `-r` does work with GNU sed, `-E` is the POSIX way to request POSIX RE syntax.

Comment: @DavidConrad thanks, fixed

Comment: Well, it is not _my_ question (I only edited it), but I thought the output examples provided were rather clear on what should happen ...